# Does Next.js have plugins?

Tags: plugins, next.js

Imagine you want to produce a specific static asset for your Next.js web app. An image collage for example, or perhaps a web manifest or site map.

My current strategy for this kind of scenario is to make a script that can produce the desired output directly in my `/public` folder, but then I have to push the built file along with my source files in my repo, which is less than ideal.

Or, I have to set up a separate parallel asset pipeline to re-create the asset when the source files change and which I would launch whenever I launch `next dev`. I would also need to run the script when `next build` is called.

In either case, I then also need to ignore the built file so it's not pushed along with the other files in `/public`…

This kind of solution feels like I'm reinventing the wheel and losing the zero-config ideal around which the Next.js ecosystem revolves.

I'd much rather provide Next.js with my custom script and just hook into the existing asset pipeline, dev server lifecycle, and build script, letting Next.js do the heavy lifting for me, hence my question:

**Does Next.js have a plugin architecture, extensions, or perhaps lifecycle hooks I could tap into to implement a custom asset pipeline?**

---

I see some pluggable loaders exist for Next.js, such as the [MDX loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/mdx), but it's not clear to me whether this is the way to go for what I'm trying to do, and I'm not finding any documentation about how to write my own loader, so I'm afraid this might not be a recommended approach…

Comment: I don't know of any direct hook-ins.  Vercel bought [turborepo](https://turborepo.org/) that could possibly help with your current dev pipeline. I just converted a couple of Next projects to it and it's been pretty easy to use.

Comment: Could what you want to achieve be done through a webpack configuration? Next.js does have plugins that [plug into the webpack config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) (like `@next/mdx`).